# how do i update record with multiple where condition

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

im new in fastapi, sqlalchemy and im trying update record with multiple where condition.

this is my model

```
class Detail(Base):
    __tablename__ = "detail_data"

    DATE = Column(String)
    DRIVER = Column(String)
    WEATHER = Column(String)
    DRIVEMODE = Column(String)
    DRIVEDISTANCE = Column(Integer)
    TEMPERATURE = Column(Integer)
    AIRCONDITIONER = Column(Boolean)
    HUMIDITY = Column(Float)
    PEOPLE = Column(Integer)
    TOTAL_WEIGHT = Column(Integer)
    TYPE = Column(String)
    START_TIME = Column(String)
    END_TIME = Column(String)
```

and i want following result

```
update detail_data
set all_column = edited_data
where "DATE" = 'YYYY-mm-dd' and "DRIVER" = 'name' and TYPE = 'type'
```

this is what i tried

```
def update_data(db:Session, date: str,...):
    q = db.query(models.Detail).\
 where(models.Detail.DATE == date, models.Detail.DRIVER == driver,models.Detail.TYPE == car_type).first()
    if q != [] :
        q.WEATHER = weather
        .
        .
        .
    db.add(q)
    db.commit()
    return q
```

but i got this err.

```
q.WEATHER = weather
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'WEATHER'
```

let me know something, how can i fix?

Comment: check what you have in `print( q )`, `print( type(q) )` - error shows that you have `None` in `q`. And if you check `print( None != [] )` then you see `True`.  I don't understand what you try to check with `!= []` but it seems you need something different.

Comment: maybe you should simply check `if q:`

Comment: First, it looks like the your `q = db.query(...)...first()` actually returns `None`. So you should check for `if q:`.  Also, are you sure that there will always be just one result satisfying your criteria? If yes, you should use `.one()` instead of `.first()`, and this will raise if no row (or multiple rows) is found.